# GKSession will get peer ids of other devices which are in background

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gksession

Will GKPeerPickerController show the peer ids of the bluetooth device which is part of one particular application in suspended mode

Scenario

I have an iOS  bluetooth application XYZ with a particular session id.Same application is running in multiple devices with same session id. Each devices should show the list of nearby devices in the XYZ application. Suppose the application has gone suspended mode  in one of the device. My question is still the other peers will get the peer ID of the bluetooth device which from the XYZ app which is in suspended mode.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No: GKSession operates on threads in your app's process, where all threads are suspended when your app is in background mode. This means that GKSession will not respond to any of the Bonjour requests or network event callbacks while your process is backgrounded, because no threads in your app will get time on the CPU.

GKSession will however work when your app is in 'inactive' mode (which happens when the user pushes the lock button on the top of the phone, or is looking at the phone call screen or the notification drawer).